# How to cryptographically verify the other party has valid private key?

Tags: encryption, private-key, public-key, encryption-asymmetric

Is there a cryptographic mechanism or algorithm to verify if the other party has a valid private
key without being able to decrypt the messages encoded with that private key?

For example with asymmetric encryption private key can decrypt messages encrypted with public key and vice versa public key can decrypt messages encrypted with private key - as I understand this is how usually digital signing works.

This mechanism doesn't work for me as on the server side I don't want to be able to decrypt messages encrypted with the private key... I just want to verify 'in some way' if the client side has a correct private key that can potentially decrypt a 'certain (encrypted) file'.

Just wanted to throw this question here if somebody has come with solution/mechanism for this specific use case? Is that even mathematically possible to achieve?

Comment: Encrypt some random data with the public key, ask the client to decrypt it and check the result.

Comment: @tkausl its simple idea, but I would still need that the public key does not decrypt data encoded with the private key... is there an asymmetric algorithm where this works?

Comment: `but I would still need that the public key does not decrypt data encoded with the private key` I'm confused now. Do you just not want to decrypt anything on the server or actively prevent the public key from being able to  decrypt? If the latter one, just don't encrypt data with the private key. (Its called signing and verifying, not en- and decrypting in this direction though).

Comment: Err, the messages are not encrypted with the other party's private key. It is encrypted with your public key and decrypted with your private key. We rather use a hybrid cryptosystem where public-key cryptosystem is used for key exchange and symmetric algorithm is used with the derived key.

Comment: This can be done with digital signatures. You have the client's public key, you ask the client to sign a challenge and you attempt to verify it with the client's public key. Actually securing this in the presence of attackers like the man-in-the-middle involves more careful design and analysis, and this is a big reason to use an existing well-respected protocol like TLS. What threats are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I need to do an ownership verification of encrypted asset. Would like to verify if other party has ability to decrypt a file.

Answer (score 0):

> For example with asymmetric encryption private key can decrypt messages encrypted with public key and vice versa public key can decrypt messages encrypted with private key - as I understand this is how usually digital signing works.

That is not quite correct. A **public key**'s job is to encrypt a message that only a **private key** can decode.

so in your case, in the simplest implementation,

- you create a key pair and give user your public key
- user create a key pair and gives you their public keyy
- you have a 'for-your-eyes-only' file which you encrypted using the user public key and placed on your server.
- the user downloads the file and decodes it using user private key

your main security concerns are;

- how you create and store your key pair, same for user
- how you exchange the public key, how you/user verify each others public key

there are tons of great blogs on the net, they answer each concern and more in great depth.